# Подсчет количества дубликатов

Tags: python

имеется список параметров объекта, например:

```
N         Событие                   Исход     
123213    Реал Мадрид-Барселона       1
123214    Фиорентина-Аталанта         X
123213    Реал Мадрид-Барселона       2
123213    Реал Мадрид-Барселона       1
123215    Венеция-Перуджа             X
123213    Реал Мадрид-Барселона       1
```

Необходимо посчитать количество дубликатов.
Ожидается, получить что-то вроде этого:

```
N         Событие                   1   X   2
123213    Реал Мадрид-Барселона     3   0   1
123214    Фиорентина-Аталанта       0   1   0
123215    Венеция-Перуджа           0   1   0
```

Можно конечно создать список списков (список кортежей и т.д), и при добавлении в него, проверять есть ли полностью идентичный набор, если нет, то добавлять.
А потом подсчитать разновидности наборов.

Может есть более элегантный способ? Может как-то с помощью dataframe в pandas

Comment: Приведите в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных в виде списка списков или списка кортежей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попытался с помощью Pandas получить требуемый результат.

Входные данные поместил в CSV и считывал оттуда:

```
N,Событие,Исход
123213,Реал Мадрид-Барселона,1
123214,Фиорентина-Аталанта,X
123213,Реал Мадрид-Барселона,2
123213,Реал Мадрид-Барселона,1
123215,Венеция-Перуджа,X
123213,Реал Мадрид-Барселона,1
```

**Код:**

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('events.csv')

res = (df.groupby(['N', 'Событие'])['Исход']
         .value_counts()
         .unstack()
         .reset_index()
         .fillna(0)
         .astype({'1': int, 'X': int, '2': int})
         .reindex(columns=['N', 'Событие', '1', 'X', '2']))
res
```

Результат:

```
Исход        N                Событие   1   X   2
    0   123213  Реал Мадрид-Барселона   3   0   1
    1   123214  Фиорентина-Аталанта     0   1   0
    2   123215  Венеция-Перуджа         0   1   0
```

**Для перевода в проценты:**

```
res.loc[:, '1':] = (res.loc[:, '1':]
                       .div(res.loc[:, '1':].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
                       .mul(100).astype(int))
res
```

Результат:

```
Исход        N                Событие    1     X     2
    0   123213  Реал Мадрид-Барселона   75     0    25
    1   123214  Фиорентина-Аталанта      0   100     0
    2   123215  Венеция-Перуджа          0   100     0
```

При сохранении, например в CSV, индекс (столбец "Исход") можно не записывать:

```
res.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: а можно ли как нибудь сделать, чтобы в каждой строчке, высчитывало не количество дубликатов, а их процент среди каждого события?

Comment: @danilshik можно, дополнил ответ. Это то, что вам нужно?

Comment: да только мне не нравится что проценты целые, для изменения необходимо сделать так?  .mul(100).astype(double))?

Comment: @danilshik как вы хотите, чтобы оно выглядело - 75.0, 25.0 и т.д.?

Comment: да, только не типа float, а типа double, а то там много значений, и нужна точность повыше, чем float

Comment: @danilshik попробуйте сначала вообще убрать часть `.astype()` и посмотрите как pandas будет выводить, он должен сам все разрулить. Если убрать `.astype()` и вывести `print(res.dtypes)`, то можно увидеть, что у этих столбцов тип `float64` и в документации написано, что это `Double precision float` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html Мне кажется, это то, что вам и нужно.

Comment: да, получилось, только мне нужно только 2 знака после запятой. И чтобы сохранялось абсолютное значение, например 20 (45.23), где в скобках процент. Можно так сделать?

Comment: @danilshik попробовал сделать, взгляните https://gist.github.com/stpnk/32ca700050c93612b33483ec090706ae значения уже будут строками при этом, не floats.

Answer (score 3):

[pandas.crosstab](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
import pandas as pd
d = '''123213 Реал Мадрид-Барселона 1
123214 Фиорентина-Аталанта X
123213 Реал Мадрид-Барселона 2
123213 Реал Мадрид-Барселона 1
123215 Венеция-Перуджа X
123213 Реал Мадрид-Барселона 1'''
lol = []
for l in d.splitlines():
  t = l.rstrip().split()
  lol.append([t[0], ' '.join(t[1:-1]), t[-1]])
print(f'Список списков: {lol}\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(lol, columns=['N', 'Событие', 'Исход'])
print(f'Вход:\n{df}\n')
df = pd.crosstab([df['N'], df['Событие']], df['Исход']).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print(f'Посчитали исходы и перевернули:\n{df}\n')
print(f'Колонки: {df.columns.tolist()}\n')
print(f'Список списков: {df.values.tolist()}')
```

**Результат:**

```
Список списков: [['123213', 'Реал Мадрид-Барселона', '1'],
                 ['123214', 'Фиорентина-Аталанта','X'],
                 ['123213', 'Реал Мадрид-Барселона', '2'],
                 ['123213', 'Реал Мадрид-Барселона', '1'],
                 ['123215', 'Венеция-Перуджа', 'X'],
                 ['123213', 'Реал Мадрид-Барселона', '1']]

Вход:
        N                Событие Исход
0  123213  Реал Мадрид-Барселона     1
1  123214    Фиорентина-Аталанта     X
2  123213  Реал Мадрид-Барселона     2
3  123213  Реал Мадрид-Барселона     1
4  123215        Венеция-Перуджа     X
5  123213  Реал Мадрид-Барселона     1

Посчитали исходы и перевернули:
        N                Событие  1  2  X
0  123213  Реал Мадрид-Барселона  3  1  0
1  123214    Фиорентина-Аталанта  0  0  1
2  123215        Венеция-Перуджа  0  0  1

Колонки: ['N', 'Событие', '1', '2', 'X']

Список списков: [['123213', 'Реал Мадрид-Барселона', 3, 1, 0], 
                 ['123214', 'Фиорентина-Аталанта', 0, 0, 1],
                 ['123215', 'Венеция-Перуджа', 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: @AndreyOdegov пример хороший, но эти данные будут либо в списке списков, либо списке кортежей. Вы же как я понял разбираете вручную текст

Comment: @danilshik, создал DataFrame из списка списков.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov, зачем нужен StringIO? Просто сделайте `for l in d.splitlines():`

Comment: @gil9red, и, действительно, зачем? :)

Answer (score 0):

Если каждая такая строчка (123213 Реал Мадрид-Барселона 1) - это объект в списке, то можно сделать из этого списка set(),  а потом методом списка `count` подсчитать количество каждой строки в исходном списке `map(lambda x: (x, data_list.count(x)), data_set)`

Только если этот список не очень большой)

Comment: вот эта строчка, будет являться внутренним списком, кортежом или другим элементом в Python. А таких объектов будет много

Comment: @danilshik Я про то, что много или нет...если есть возможность каждый раз это все не считать - то лучше ввести какие то переменные с счетчиками или типо того. А то лопатить каждый раз этот список долго, но метод который в ответе работать должен.  К `set` все приведется быстро, остается только посчитать вхождения или в цикле (за один проход) или так, как удобнее.